# Eliminating parameter from parametric equation

Tags: equation-solving, parametric-functions

In *Mathematica* Online I tried:

```
Eliminate[{x == t + t^3, y == t - t^3, z == 1 + t^4}, {t}]
```

> ```
> x^2 == -4 + y^2 + 4 z && 
> x y z == -4 + 2 y^2 + 6 z - y^2 z - 2 z^2 &&
> x (-2 + z) z == y (4 - 2 y^2 - 4 z - z^2) && 
> x (-2 + y^2 + z) == y (2 - y^2 -3 z) && 
> y^4 + y^2 (-4 + 4 z) == -4 + 8 z - 5 z^2 + z^3
> ```

Apart from the question of how to understand the answer, this is not what I expected. What I expected was

> ```
> (x^2 + y^2)^2 == (x^2 - y^2)z^2
> ```

I consider my expectation reasonable because

```
Simplify[((t+t^3)^2 + (t-t^3)^2)^2 - ((t+t^3)^2 -(t-t^3)^2)*(1+t^4)^2]
```

gives `0`.

Is there a better way to achieve the elimination of `t`?

I also tried

```
Eliminate[{
  (x^2 + y^2)^2 == (x^2 - y^2)*z^2, 
  u == 2*x*(x^2 + y^2) - x*z^2, 
  v == 2*y*(x^2 + y^2) + y* z^2, 
  w == z*(y^2 - x^2)}, 
  {x, y, z}]
```

which gave a neat solution:

> ```
> (-15u^4 - 78u^2v^2 - 15v^4)w^2 + (-48u^2 + 48v^2)w^4 + 64w^6 == 
>   u^6 - 3u^4v^2 + 3u^2v^4 - v^6
> ```

Considering such a result I thought *Mathematica* would be able to eliminate `t` in my first example as well.

#### Edit

Just right now I discovered that the following command gives the correct and expected result:

```
Eliminate[{x == (t + t^3)/(1 + t^4), y == (t - t^3)/(1 + t^4)}, {t}]
```

Is using three parameter `x, y, z` instead of only `x, y` too much for *Mathematica*?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Actually `FullSimplify@Eliminate[{x == (t + t^3)/(1 + t^4), y == (t - t^3)/(1 + t^4)}, {t}]` doesn't give the result you expect. `z^2` is missing!

Comment: Your expectations are amiss for sound geometric reasons. You have a parametrized curve in three dimensions. Eliminating the parameter cannot give a single equation, as that would be a surface. That it gave more than two equations is due to `Eliminate` computing a Groebner bases, since these often contain more polynomials than the minimum needed to define the underlying ideal.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not too much for Mathematica. What you expect and the result given by Mathematica are the same thing. This can be tested by

```
e = Eliminate[{x == t + t^3, y == t - t^3, z == 1 + t^4}, t];
s = Solve[e, {x, y}];
AllTrue[s, ((x^2 + y^2)^2 == (x^2 - y^2) z^2 /. # // FullSimplify) &]
```

which gives `True`.

The question is more like how you could manipulate the result into the form that you expect. One way to do that is

```
(
  FullSimplify@Eliminate[
    {
      x == t + t^3,
      y == t - t^3,
      z == 1 + t^4, 
      u == x^2 + y^2,
      v == x^2 - y^2
    },
    {x, y, t}
  ] /. z^2 -> zsq // Eliminate[#, z] &
) /. {zsq -> z^2, u -> x^2 + y^2, v -> x^2 - y^2}
```

As this is an aesthetic matter it's not surprising that human intervention is needed.

Comment: O well. Do you know what Math. means by `x^2 == -4 + y^2 + 4 z && .. expr. 2 && expr. 3 && ..` etc.' ?`

Comment: Why do you inout `s = Solve[e, {x, y}];` instead of s = Solve[e, {x, y, z}]; ?

Comment: Consider for example `{x == t + t^3, y == t - t^3, z == 1 + t^4}`. This can be written as a logical combination `x == t + t^3 && y == t - t^3 && z == 1 + t^4`. The latter form can be intuitively read as like  '`t` has to the satisfy the first expression AND the second one AND the third one'.

Comment: With `s = Solve[e, {x, y}]`, `e` is recast as a pair of $x(z)$ and $y(z)$ to be inserted into your $(x^2 + y^2)^2 = (x^2 - y^2) z^2$ for verification. Note that there are several possibilities (four) for the pair. All are verified.